# what is the use of "remote(client) port" for inbound firewall rule?

Tags: networking, firewall

In firewall settings, local port for inbound rule is pretty obvious: that is the port you want to listen.
However, **remote port** sounds nonsense: In typical protocol, client uses arbitrary port so restricting remote port will break your service.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdHzW.png]
image is borrowed from [What are differnet between local port and remote port of firewall in Windows 2016 server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/996598/what-are-differnet-between-local-port-and-remote-port-of-firewall-in-windows-201)
Although the image is windows firewall settings, I guess other firewalls have similar.

Is there any case to restrict client port(remote port) for inbound traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many software and protocols where clients may request servers from fixed ports.

- What comes in my mind is the DNS, where client request (from port 53) a remote server (port 53). So a in-depth defense rule at your server side would be to only allow remote clients from their remote port 53.
- I think that ldap protocol does the same: client is requesting from a fixed and well defined port.
- You may also think of various synchronisations services (like SMB, NFS maybe, and various others..).
- You may also define remote ports range firewalling, in example, to ensure that a client is talking from a remote unprivileged port

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that DNS uses port 53 for both server and client. thanks!